# How to convert a List returned from JSP to an Array of Strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I'm having a HTML page with JSP in it and returned a List from JSP.

```
<input type="hidden" id="role" value="${sessionScope.rolePermissionsList}" />
```

Using JavaScript, i tried to display the List:

```
var rolesList = document.getElementById('role');
console.log(role.value);
```

It displayed the below result on the browser's console:

```
[ PR_1 , PR_2, PR_3, PR_4 ]
```

I want this output to be converted to an Array of Strings.

> I expected the output to be in this way [ "PR_1" , "PR_2", "PR_3",
>   "PR_4" ]

Can anyone tell me how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `[ PR_1 , PR_2, PR_3, PR_4 ]` is a string, you can use the below to convert into an array of strings.

```js
var rolesList = "[PR_1, PR_2, PR_3, PR_4]";
console.log(rolesList.match(/\[(.*?)\]/)[1].split(", "));
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Perfect !